# determine the amount of ambient light levels

Tags: python, for-loop, sensors, light, ambient

For this program I am working with python.

I am supposed to move the robot to a random position and rotate it 360 degrees. I have to assign 15 readings from all three light sensors to three different lists.

I then have to calculate the average of the light value from each sensor, and then determine the maximum and minimum values for each sensor.

I then have to calculate and display the average of the light values from all three sensors, and have it announce the average light value of its surrounding and whether its too bright or too dark.

I believe that I have done all this, but my program does not work. For instance, my robot moves in random position and then turns 360 degrees, but then the program just stops and I can't figure out why.

An error appears that says:

```
max() arg is an empty sequence
```

If someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong that would be great!
Thank you so much!!!

This is my program:

```
from myro import *
init("simulator")

def pressC():
    entry = " "
    while(entry != "c"):
        entry = raw_input("Press c to continue: ")

def movement():
    rightSensor = []
    centerSensor = []
    leftSensor = []
    return rightSensor
    return centerSensor
    return leftSensor

    for index in range(1,15):
        rightSensor.append(getLight("right"))
        centerSensor.append(getLight("center"))
        leftSensor.append(getLight("left"))

def average():
    rightSensor = []
    centerSensor = []
    leftSensor = []
    sumRight = 0
    sumCenter = 0
    sumLeft = 0

    for index in range(len(rightSensor)):
        sumRight = sumRight + rightSensor[index]
        averageRight = sumRight / 15

    for index in range(len(centerSensor)):
        sumCenter = sumCenter + centerSensor[index]
        averageCenter = sumCenter / 15
        while averageCenter > 100:
            speak("Its too dark. I need light")
        else:
            speak("Its so bright")

    for index in range(len(leftSensor)):
        sumLeft = sumLeft + leftSensor[index]
        averageLeft = sumLeft / 15

    max(rightSensor)
    min(rightSensor)
    max(centerSensor)
    min(centerSensor)
    max(leftSensor)
    min(leftSensor)

    print "Left Avg: " + str(averageLeft), "Max: " + str(leftSensor), "Min: " + str(leftSensor)
    print "Center Avg: " + str(averageCenter), "Max: " + str(centerSensor), "Min: " + str(centerSensor)
    print "Right Avg: " + str(averageRight), "Max: " + str(rightSensor), "Min: " + str(rightSensor)


def main():
    pressC()
    forward(1,1)
    rotate(1)
    wait(7)
    stop()
    movement()
    average()

main()
```

Comment: You even keep it a secret at which line the error occurred? Man, you really don't want help...

Comment: Im sorry but this is what the complete error says:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\", line 67, in -toplevel-
    main()
  File "C:\Users\", line 65, in main
    average()
  File "C:\Users\", line 46, in average
    max(rightSensor)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: what is the meaning of the three consecutive return statements `return rightSensor` `return centerSensor` `return leftSensor`? Only the first one will ever be executed.

Comment: I thought I had to return them to use them as values. Are they not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

This is the relevant part of your code:

```
def average():
    rightSensor = []
    (do stuff that does not change rightSensor)
    max(rightSensor)
```

No wonder it's empty then.